# "Example Questions" section in Area51 profile should be sortable by proposal

Tags: feature-request, area-51, profile-page, sorting

Neither in the profile, nor on a proposal's site there is a sort order that lets you easily compare the example questions you posted for that question. For example this would be useful to find the worst rated of the examples you posted and replace them with better ones.

For that it would be useful to have a sorting option for the "Example Question" part of the profile page that groups together questions belonging to the same proposal, so that they appear next to each other. The ordering inside of these groups doesn't really matter since it can only be up to five entries each, which is small enough to not need a special sorting.